# Error parsing snippet xml: unexpected end of data

Tags: xml, parsing, code-snippets

```
<snippet>
    <content>
      <![CDATA[${1:type} ${2:name} (${3:void}){
               ${5}; return ${4:able};}]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>f,fn,fct</tabTrigger>
    <description>decl funct<description>
    <scope>source.c99</scope>
</snippet>
```

Error parsing snippet xml: unexpected end of data in file Packages/User/c99/funct.sublime-snippet on line 12

Comment: You missed to close `<description>` correctly. End tag should be `</description>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closing tag `<description>` in the message is not good. Fix it to `</description>`.

So your xml must be :

```
<snippet>
    <content>
        <![CDATA[
    ${1:type} ${2:name} (${3:void})
    {
        ${5}
        return ${4:able};
    }
    ]]>
    </content>
    <tabTrigger>f,fn,fct</tabTrigger>
    <description>decl funct</description>
    <scope>source.c99</scope>
</snippet>
```